# SQL table names

Tags: sql

I want to see the variables in a specific table, however I am not sure what the full table name is. Which function can I use for that?

For now I used

```
select top 10* 
from VIF_%
```

But that doesn't work. I only know that the table name contains `VIF`.

Comment: pls. tag the DBMS (MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle) which u r using.

Comment: Tables don't contain "variables".

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Check out dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may use the below query to handle table name:(If it is MS SQL)

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%VIF%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using MS SQL, you can use the following code.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%VIF%'
```

OR

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%VIF%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table_name FROM user_tables where owner = "X"
```

where X Is the username of person who created tables.
Then to find specific column use 
    `desc X`